# Runs in Ubuntu, SegFault in Debian (C, strtok)

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, debian, strtok

My program is completely done, and works exactly as it should in Ubuntu 12.04. However, when I try to compile it on a Debian VM, it gives me a segfault error. The code that is giving a segfault is:

```
printf("Going to location: /bin/%s\n", input2[0]);
```

Input2 is a char*, because I needed to use the strtok function (requires char* as argument I believe). I have posted my code below, as well as Eclipse debug's Variable window to show the values in the array.

Here is the Variable window to help with my question:
[image]

I originally thought the error was in the array2 itself, because the unused values terminated with 0x0 and not \0. I later found out that 0x0 and \0 are just different ways of expressing the null terminator so that wasn't the problem. I also tried

```
printf("Going to location: /bin/%s\n", *input2[0]);
```

with the dereference because input2 supposedly is a pointer to a string, but that didn't work either.

I am quite confused here; is the problem due to a difference between Ubuntu and Debian, or is the problem actually because of how I used my arrays? I am leaning towards the latter, but I am quite confused as to what is wrong.

Here is my code until the segfault. The rest is just fork() and execvp(), which works fine:

```
int flag = 0;
int i = 0;
int status;
char *s; //for strchr, strtok
char input[15] = "";
char *input2[5];
//char input2[5];

//Prompt
printf("Please enter prompt:\n");

//Reads in input
fgets(input, 14, stdin);

//Remove \n
int len = strlen(input); //Warning: Implicit declaration of strlen and Incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function strlen
if (len > 0 && input[len-1] == '\n')
    input[len-1] = ' ';

//Check for & via strchr
s = strchr (input, '&'); //Warning: Implicit declaration of strchr and Incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function strchr
if (s != NULL) { //If there is a &
    printf("'&' detected. Program not waiting.\n");
    //printf ("'&' Found at %s\n", s);
    flag = 1;
}


//Now for strtok
input2[i] = strtok(input, " "); //Warning: Implicit declaration of function strtok and Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast

while(input2[i] != NULL)
{
    input2[++i] = strtok( NULL, " "); //Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast
}

if (flag == 1) {
    i = i - 1; //Removes & from total number of arguments
}

//Sets null terminator for unused slots. (Is this step necessary? Does the C compiler know when to stop?)
int c = i;
while (c < 5) {
    input2[c] = '\0';
    c++;
}

printf("Going to location: /bin/%s\n", input2[0]); //SegFault
```

**Edit:** I have added the warnings as comments to my code. Most of them are implicit declaration warnings, and a few are "Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast". I will be checking those out now.

Comment: The problem surely has something to with your program.  It is not fundamentally due to a difference between Ubuntu and Debian.  If your program segfaults then it is a pretty safe assumption that it is *your* fault.

Comment: `fgets(input, 100, stdin)` into a buffer only declared as `char input[15]` has recipe-for-disaster written all over it from the get-go.

Comment: That 15 and 100 discrepancy was my bad! It is 15 on the actual code; I was changing things around earlier. "ls" and "pwd" will be the only inputs. I've been trying various other things, but still haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Have you tried running through valgrind? Being able to use valgrind is a very valuable skill that will probably come in handy in the future.

Comment: This program compiles?  `input2[c] = '\0';` assigns a `char` to a `char *`.  Have you compiled with warnings like `-Wall` and `-Wextra`?

Comment: @indiv Thanks for pointing that out! I will check the part that contains input2p[c] = '\0' right now. As for compiling, the program does compile on both machines, but with a few warnings (edited on main post)

Comment: Regarding your text:   "I late found out that 0x0 and \0 are just different ways of expressing the null terminator so that wasn't the problem.".  They are not at all the same.  0 is a null pointer.  A pointer pointing to nothing that is illegal to dereference.  Whereas a non-zero pointer pointing to the value 0 (`'\0'`) is an empty string.  Those warnings you're ignoring are bugs in your program that need to be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You make the array `input` large enough to accommodate 14 chars plus a terminator, but you tell fgets() that it is big enough to accommodate 99.  You have undefined behavior if the program reads more than 14.

You tokenize the input into an unpredictable number of tokens, but you reserve space for at most 5.  If the input contains more, then you have undefined behavior.

You assume that if the '&' character is present in the input then it is at the end, as a separate token.

If the input is a blank line, then `strtok()` probably returns NULL for the first token, which might cause a segfault on the indicated line.

It the value of input2[0] is as depicted in the question, however, then there is no reason for `printf()` to segfault.  I conclude that either the variable contains something different, or that the segfault occurs elsewhere.

Comment: For example, it may segfault soon after that line.  Say, if it does something involving `strlen(input2[1])`, since, as @indiv observed, you've set the other `input2[]` elements to NULL pointers.  (and your data show this, too.)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had 15 originally in the fgets (made some changes before pasting over), but changed it to 14 now. The input is always "ls" or "pwd" with or without an & at the end, so I made the arrays small. I am pretty confused too, since the debug window in Eclipse shows that it is working great. I do have a few warnings in Eclipse though. I will check them out now.

Answer (score 2):

**I FOUND THE ERROR!**

I was looking through my warnings as some of you suggested, and while looking through the implicit declaration warning posts on Stack Overflow, I found that I was missing an:

```
#include <string.h>
```

header. That fixed everything! I have no errors now.

I am still a little confused here though. What did string.h give me that was not making my program work earlier? I noticed that string.h included size_t which is the return type for strlen and strchr. Was that it? It also contains a NULL "macro" that contained the value of a null pointer constant. What is so special about this that separated it from the previous NULL?

Lastly, in what cases would programs need to include string.h? Is the only time when we need to include that is when we want to use string-related functions such as strchr, strcat, strcpy and such? In normal cases when we just want to use a string to store a phrase, we would not need to include string.h, is that correct?

Again, thank you for all the help!

Comment: That assuredly did not fix *everything*, but I can believe that you stopped getting a segfault (which indeed did not arise from the `printf()` call if including the header made it stop).  I would guess that on the machine where your program worked, pointers are the same size as int, but on the machine where the program segfaulted they are different sizes.  That could easily be the case if the former is running a 32-bit kernel and the latter a 64-bit kernel.  If you do not provide function prototypes (via a header) then the compiler may guess argument types wrongly.

Comment: Never *assume* that it is safe to ignore a compiler warning.  The compiler emits them for your benefit.  Occasionally they really are ok, but you should be certain you know why they are ok before you dismiss them.

Comment: More directly to your questions: (1) the most important thing the header provided was function prototypes; (2) NULL is a macro, not a language built-in, and unless something is dreadfully wrong, the definition in string.h is equivalent to any others in the system header files; (3) you need to include string.h in source files that use the string functions.  Function documentation (among other things) should tell you.  In particular, commands such as `man 3 strcpy` should show what header file(s) to include.

Comment: The `string.h` "fix" (if you can call it that) was because of two more warnings also being ignored, one that says something to the effect of "function `strtok` implicitly returns `int`" and then "assigning `int` to lvalue of type `char*`. I suspect your Debian VM platform is 64bit, with a 32bit native `int`, As such failure to include `string.h` meant no prototype of `strtok`, and therefore it was treated as `int strtok()`. The result is half of each 64bit pointer was being thrown out with the assumed `int` result, which you wouldn't know until you tried to dereference one.